# vNext is missing System.Drawing.Color

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I'm starting to dig vNext until today I hit a wall: I need a class to represent color and the namespace is missing. I need it to return a color status.

Is there another way to access the Color class or something similar that I never heard of?

Also I want to stick to dnxcore50 only if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks to me like [some of the System.Drawing primitives are coming in beta7](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1563)

but color is still under [design discussion and no milestone yet assigned](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2315)

Comment: Well I guess I could live without it since I'm converting the color to string anyway.